# Vimeo: How to activate captions by default?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player

We have embedded player on our site.
VTT French captions were been uploaded.

We need the captions to be activated by default.

Currently its not happening. The captions are available, `CC` button is there, and we can switch them ON while playing. But we do want the captions to show automatically.

The embed code is as follows:
`<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/[videoid]?texttrack=fr" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

According to [Vimeo' docs](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027818211-Enabling-Captions-and-Subtitles-in-Embeds-by-Default) **texttrack=fr** is what should make the captions to show automatically.

The video has language set to `English`.

Any idea on how to solve our problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find an answer.
For those who faces the same issue: make sure that language in the embedding code matches the language selected, when captions were uploaded within Vimeo.

Embed code we had was `texttrack=fr`, but captions were uploaded as `Language - French (Canada)`.
We changed to `texttrack=fr-ca` and all is good now.

You may also need to play with type of data you upload: Subtitles or Captions

Comment: Just adding a little comment to this: **if the user has chosen to display some subtitles track when he was watching some video _(any video)_ on Vimeo the last time (even embedded), Vimeo will automatically play the first subtitle track on your video, if there is any**. To disable this behaviour and force the video to start playing without any subtitles turned on by default (even if there are subtitles tracks present in the video), add parameter `?texttrack=false`. User will then be able to manually turn on some specific subtitle track, but no subtitles will be on by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that at this point in time, Vimeo language variables are case-sensitive and "texttrack=fr-ca" does not work. But "texttrack=fr-CA" does work. Vimeo has identified this as an issue and may make the variable non-case-sensitive in the future.